# Python 3.4 / Notepad++ 6.5 Hex Characters Replacement

Tags: python-3.x, hex, notepad++

I use Python 3.4.2 (Windows 7) and Notepad++ 6.5.5 (Windows 7).

When I open a file1.txt, which contains rows of data on countries, some characters appear as xF4 in white font colour, surrounded by a black background rectangle. I would like Python to replace those xF4 with the correct character: ô.

Here is what I have come up with, so far:

```
f1 = open('C:\\ABCD\\file1.txt', 'r')
f2 = open('C:\\ABCD\\file2.txt', 'w')
for line in f1:
    f2.write(line.replace('&#xF4;', 'ô'))
f1.close()
f2.close()
```

It does not do the job. It seems that the way I write "'ô'" is the problem.

I would appreciate your help on this.

Comment: Are you sure this issue is not to do with the way Notepad++ represents these characters?

Comment: Could you show us your file?

Comment: If I open the file with the Windows 7 notepad/wordpad, the ô is indeed displayed correctly. However, when I try to load the file into an sql table, the load process stops at the row containing xF4/ô and yells that the character is invalid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a problem of encoding. `0xF4` is indeed the code of `ô` in Windows 1252 charset (or Latin1 or iso-8859-1)

But if Notepad++ is configured to use and display UTF8, 0xF4 in **not** a valid UTF8 character. The correct utf8 representation is 0xC3, 0xB4.

Python is able to do charset conversion is that is what you want

```
with open('latin.txt', 'rb') as fdin, open('utf.txt', 'wb') as fdout:
    for line in fdin:
        fdout.write(line.decode('latin1').encode('utf8'))
```

(all is done in binary mode to be compatible with python 2 and python 3)

But a simpler alternative would be to configure Notepad++ to use latin1 charset.

Edit:

As suggested by Fenikso, as you say you use Python3, you can also do :

```
with open('latin.txt', 'r', encoding='latin1') as fdin, open('utf.txt',
        'w', encoding='utf8') as fdout:
    for line in fdin:
        fdout.write(line)
```

Comment: If the `f2` needs to be a specific encoding, why not to just open it as such? E.g. `f2 = open('C:\\ABCD\\file2.txt', 'w', encoding='UTF-8')`.

Comment: @Fenikso Because the question was tagged as `python` not as `python3` and that this way works under both. But you are right, Python3 was in the title ...

Comment: Serge: I changed the tag to python3, thank you for your answer and apologies for the confusion.